# Possible to create universal linux program?

Tags: c, linux, binary, universal-binary

In mac os x, you can combine 32bit, powerpc and 64bit binaries in one executable using "lipo" is something like this possible in linux?

Comment: Scripts probably don't count? ;)

Comment: @MSalters Possibly if i created a "wrapper" script that detects if the os is 64bit capable and open the correct version? but i'd rather the script be written in C, how could i do that?

Comment: Not really. The C-compiled-for-ARM version wouldn't run on x86 and vice versa. A shell script can start an ARM binary on ARM, an x86 binary on x86, etc. However, it gets very very ugly if you try to stuff all those binaries in the shell script with Base 64 encoding, which you'd need to do to achieve the "one executable" goal - hence the smiley.

Comment: Is it possible to detect an x86_64 or i386 OS like "uname -m" does in plain c?

Comment: No, that's the wrong way around. You must tell your compiler what architecture to compile for, and therefore it doesn't make sense to ask later. The only exception is the pair x86/x64, since the latter can run x86 exectuables too. But that's far less distinction than `uname -m` gives you.

Comment: How does uname -m work then? i've been looking in uname.c in coreutils but doesn't seam to be anything that "checks" for 64bit/32bit

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/utsname.h.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Fatelf (available at http://icculus.org/fatelf/ ) is what you are actually asking for, but it requires certain patches to kernel, glibc, gdb etc. So it's currently not for the faint of heart to use. It may be a reasonable burden for a developer to compile on a modified system, but it also requires client-side systems to be modified, too.

Comment: The problem is that the end users the program would be for probably wouldn't know if they are using a 64bit or 32bit OS. I was thinking of something that would use the 64bit version if possible but fail to 32bit if not

Comment: @Daniel, do you have an advantage in running the 64bit exe?  64bit linux is able to run 32 bits exe without problem.

Comment: @AProgrammer Although there might be little advantage (if any) at all, i'm trying to keep all my programs 64bit capable

Comment: You might as well use a script as a frontend for the user. Suppose you have the binary named "my-game". Rename the 64bit version as my-game-x86_64 and 32bit version as my-game-i386. Then create a script with the name "my-game", which basically runs "my-game-\`uname -m\`".

Comment: Note - the amd64 port on most distros *won't* run 32 bit binaries. If you're lucky, you might have a 32-bit version of libc (not usually installed by default though), but as for other libraries you'd be very lucky to get them. Basically, you have to ship 64-bit binaries for 64-bit customers on Linux, and 32- for 32.